# In Perl, how can I extract email addresses from lines in log files?

Tags: regex, perl

I am looking to trim a string that will be created from reading in a file line by line. However i want to pull out only the email from the string, but it will change every time. The only contant is the domain, for example `@domain.com`.

So for the input string of

```
 00:00:50,004 ERROR [SynchronousCallback] Cannot process resource: test.test@domain.com  Channel: channel16
```

What regular expression will look for `@domain.com` and pull out all `test.test@domain.com`. Ive got a regex that will look for the string `m/@domain.com/i` but i dont know how to then manipulate the string once the `@domain.com` has been located in the whole string.

The output i would like would be just the email `test.test@domain.com`

Comment: `/(.*?@domain.com)/i` would be the most simplistic version, capturing (hopefully) a whole email address into $1.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict; use warnings;
use Email::Address;


while (my $line = <DATA>) {
    my ($addr) = Email::Address->parse($line);
    print $addr->address, "\n";
}

__DATA__
00:00:50,004 ERROR [SynchronousCallback] Cannot process resource: test.test@domain.com  Channel: channel16
```

Output:

```
C:\temp> tt
test.test@domain.com
```

Answer (score 3):

Will there always be whitespace immediately preceding the e-mail address? If so, you can use something like:

```
m/\s([^\s\@]+\@domain.com)/i
```

Then you can retrieve the whole e-mail address by looking at `$1`.

Comment: This will not work as it stands as it will interpolate the array `@domain` into the regex. It will either fail or produce the wrong results.

Answer (score 0):

If you need all result (more than one email per line) for a regexp you could do this:

```
while ($str =~ s# ([^ ]+\@domain.com)##i){
  my $email = $1;
  print $email."\n";
}
```

regards,

Comment: Thank you very much, for the reply. Its a nice solution however for this instance there will only ever be one email per line.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you simply need to capture all non-whitespace characters preceding the domain string using `/\S+\@domain\.com/`. This program shows the principle.

```perl
my $s = '00:00:50,004 ERROR [SynchronousCallback] Cannot process resource: test.test@domain.com  Channel: channel16';
print "$_\n" for $s =~ /\S+\@domain\.com/gi;
```

**output**

```
test.test@domain.com
```